# .NET Console app alongside web app to process long-running tasks

Tags: .net, console-application

My ASP.NET web application provides an import functionality that basically accepts an excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet will then need to be processed, parsed, validated, etc. This could take quite a long time depending on the size of the spreadsheet.
Rather than doing this on the web application, I decided to write a console app that is responsible for processing long-running tasks.

The architecture is really simple, there is a table named "job_queue" that the web app writes to whenever an import is initiated, containing all the info required for an import. The console app then picks up uncompleted jobs from the queue, process them, and mark them as complete so they won't be picked up again.

The console app needs to be on standby mode at all times, ready to pick up new jobs by repeatedly checking the "job_queue" table.

My question is what is the best solution for the console app?

Currently I have something like this that runs forever. However it seems to be very resource intensive and sometimes hangs and requires a restart of the console app.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true) // Keep repeating the same thing
    {
        ProcessJobs();
    }
}
```

How can I improve this code so that it could be more resource friendly and more robust?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do is to set up a Windows Scheduled Task that executes your console application on a scheduled basis. You can remove the while loop from your console and simply rely on Windows to run your console application as often as you require.

Windows Scheduled Tasks can also be configured to automatically restart in the event it fails or becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I ended up adopting this approach. I set up the scheduled task to run the console app every 5 mins then quits (rather than an infinite loop). This gets around the issue with the process hanging since a new process is started every time. The only downside is there is a max wait of 5 mins for a new background job to be processed by the console app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a scheduled task is not the preferable solution, since you keep querying the database until you get the next file. Not very efficient.
Instead, you can use a FileSystemWatcher to get notified when a new file is created on disk and then handle that file.

http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/how-build-folder-watcher-service-c

Another option - If your process is more complex (for instance: you want to be able to continue reading from the middle of the file, you want to process specific files in specific times ets), you can use WWF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734631%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

HTH

Comment: the spreadsheet file gets stored in database not in file system.